# How to check if an entry is updated with SQLAlchemy ORM?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have an ETL pipeline that makes me a summary about a customer, computing its score. Imagine the customer summary is like this (using SQL alchemy):

```
class CustomerSummary(db.Model):
    company_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('company.id'), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    customer_id = Column(String(256), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    customer_score = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

    def to_dict(self):
        return {'company_id':self.company_id, 'customer_id': self.customer_id, 'customer_score': 
                self.customer_score}
```

This scheduler runs everyday to compute new customer scores.

Now, I want to persist those updates and keep a list of the updates based on what I already have at my DB, so I can call a webhook with it

I've checked on session.dirty and session.new for every merge, but dirty returns all inputs, no matter if the are exactly the same.

E.G.:

```
def persist_customer_summaries(customer_summary_list, db):
    webhook_data = {'new':[],'updated':[]}
    for customer_summary in customer_summary_list:
        db.session.merge(customer_summary) # Also, any idea about some merge_all?
        if db.session.new:
            webhook_data['new'].append(customer_summary.to_dict())
        elif db.session.dirty:
            webhook_data['updated'].append(customer_summary.to_dict())
        db.session.commit() # I have to commit at each merge, right?
    return webhook_data
```

How can I check, for example, only customer summaries where the score is changed?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get your primary keys in the customer_summary_list list? I expect you make a db query to obtain existing customers. If the customer is not found, then you make a new instance, right? THIS is the place where you can tell that's a new customer.

Then you calculate the new rating. THIS is the place where you can tell whether customer's rating has changed.

You cannot rely on dirty. The docs say: *Note that this ‘dirty’ calculation is ‘optimistic’; most attribute-setting or collection modification operations will mark an instance as ‘dirty’ and place it in this set, even if there is no net change* (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.dirty)

Once you start calculating the changes yourself, you can commit just once at the end.

Comment: As I mentioned, these id's come from the ETL. They are the customer identification, and the company ID. As soon as I get the data, I could check these in a loop, but that would add a significant overhead to my computing for each IO call to db. Im looking for something more batch-esque (I expect to process LARGE amounts of data soon, so 1 IO call for each entry would not be nice). Since I did not find any batch strategy, I was looking for any builtin structure that may help speed this up... Any other ideas here?